# Creating variable with dynamic names - Java

Tags: java, collections

I have an ArrayList of ArrayLists of words where Word is a class.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>> arrayColumns = new ArrayList();
```

with every new column I have to create a new ArrayList of Words and then add that to arrayColumns.

This ArrayList I am creating dynamically and want to name it as arrayWordColumn1, arrayWordColumn2 etc with the addition of every new column. As I don't know how many columns will be there I am trying to write a method to create an ArrayList. Something Like :

```
public ArrayList<OCRWord> createColumn (count){
    ArrayList<OCRWord> arrayWordColumn+count = new ArrayList();
    return ArrayList;
}
```

How can I create arrayLists in such a manner so that if count is 1,2,3,4... it should create ArrayLists with names arrayWordColumn1, arrayWordColumn2, arrayWordColumn3 etc.?

In Short the name `arrayWordColumn1` should be formed by concatenating two things --> arrayWordColumn + count where count will be 1,2,3,4...

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: How does name matter when arrayColumns will have only reference of your dynamically created array list?

Comment: well you could use a `Map<String,List<Word>>`, which i think gets as close as possible to what you would like to have as "variable" name, where the `key` of the map would represent your "variable" name.

Comment: Variables can't have dynamic names, and there isn't a good reason why they should.

Comment: Code to the interface, not the implementation, and stop using raw types. The declaration should be `List<List<Word>> arrayColumns = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1):

Probably like this

```
Map<String,List<Word>> map = new HashMap();
map.put("arrayWordColumn1", list);
```

Comment: Moving to map won't be a good choice for me as there are a lot of dependencies on this. And after that the question remains the same that how can I name the variable arrayWordColumn1, arrayWordColumn2... etc by concatenating two variables like String + count

Comment: In Java you can't. All variables must be declared at compile time. You may create a "named reference" by a Map or any other dynamic data structure.

Comment: `new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 1):

Declare a map string, list

```
Map<String,List<Word>> myDynamicMap = new HashMap<>();
```

to add dynamic variables:

```
myDynamicMap.put("ListWord_1", list1);
myDynamicMap.put("ListWord_2", someList);
myDynamicMap.put("ListWord_3", anotherList);
```

to get a list from the map:

```
myDynamicMap.get("ListWord_3");
```

Comment: i´m just going to note that a `Map<Integer,List<Word>>` might be the smoother choice here, as you pretty much only care for the last number(s) even though.

Comment: Moving to map won't be a good choice for me as there are a lot of dependencies on this. And after that the question remains the same that how can I name the variable ListWord_1, ListWord_2, ListWord_3...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this stucture :
ArrayList < Map > i think that's better
ArrayList of Map that has Integer Key and list of word is better in the access when you add a new list of word you should use new Integer(value) 
good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can get the names of the variables at runtime. After getting these variable names, you can create references by using Map or any other structure, you want.

[how to get variable names at runtime](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/118)

The summary of this is given as follows;

> Provide a mechanism to easily and reliably retrieve the parameter
>   names of methods and constructors at runtime via core reflection.